# How can i convert jenkins Build Duration from milliseconds to hr:min:sec

Tags: curl, jenkins, awk

i can get the jenkins Build Duration using the Rest API via curl , but the time is in milliseconds.

```
curl -s "$JOB_URL/$BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?tree=duration
```

I am looking for a way to get the time in the standard format i.e., **hr:min:sec**
i tried this  till now

```
curl -s "$JOB_URL/$BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?tree=duration | awk -F : '{ print $2 }' | awk -F } '{ printf "%i hr %i min %i sec", ($1 / 3600000), ($1 % 3600000)/60000 , ($1 % 100)}'
```

this is definitely not correct as the time that the URL gives in milliseconds is `417597` but it gives in **hr:min:sec** as `0 hr 6 min 97 sec`

```
curl -s $JOB_URL/3458/api/json?tree=duration
{"duration":417597}

curl -s $JOB_URL/3458/api/json?tree=duration | awk -F : '{ print $2 }' | awk -F } '{ printf "%i hr %i min %i sec", ($1 / 3600000), ($1 % 3600000)/60000 , ($1 % 100)}'
0 hr 6 min 97 sec
```

The minute and hour conversion is correct.
I am stuck in the seconds conversion
Can someone please suggest what is wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, could you please post output of `curl` command once in your post with CODE TAGS? Will be helpful for us to help you, cheers :)

Comment: edited the question..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 417597 | awk '
{  t_sec = int($0/1000)
   divmod(t_sec, 60); t_min = Q; sec = R
   divmod(t_min, 60);    hr = Q; min = R
   printf "%s hr %s min %s sec\n", hr, min, sec
}
function divmod(a, b) { # quotient and remainder
    Q = int(a / b)
    R = a - Q * b
}'
```

Returns

```
0 hr 6 min 57 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

From the duration value, you can simply calculate the value in groovy :D

## Groovy

```
def duration = 635309

// Roud the hour
double hour = Double.valueOf((duration / 3600000)).round()
def hourStr = hour > 0 ? " ${hour}h" : ""

// Handle minute parts
double totalMin = Double.valueOf((duration % 3600000)/60000).round(2)
def realMin = "${totalMin}".split("\\.")
def min = Integer.valueOf(realMin[0])
def minStr = Integer.valueOf(min) > 0 ? "${min}min" : ""

// Handle the reminder of seconds
def realSec = realMin[1]
double secVal = Double.valueOf("0.${realSec}") * 60
def sec = "${secVal}".split("\\.")[0]
sec = Integer.valueOf(sec) > 0 ? "${sec}sec" : ""

println "Duration is Build time${hourStr} ${minStr} ${sec}"
```

## Execution

**Duration is Build time 10min 35sec**